# Multinomial Distribution

Tags: probability

I'm not able to follow the bit which i've highlighted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could anyone also explain why the supports are independent?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is the law of total probability, which gives
$$
P(X=x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(N=n\,\,;\,\,X=x).
$$
Now note that the probability on the right hand side is zero if $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i\neq n$, since $X|N=n\sim \text{ Multinomial}(n,p)$. This means that the sum over $n$ reduces to only one case, namely when $n = \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i$, giving us
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(N=n\,\,;\,\,X=x) = P(N = \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i\,\,;\,\,X=x).
$$
At this point both the indicators in the formula above the green highlighted sentence are 1 resulting in the given answer.

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This passage means that the value of $N$ is known once the value of $X$ is given. Specifically, $N = \sum_{i=1}^{k}{X_{i}}$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
f_{X,N}(x,n) &= f_{X}(x) \cdot I\left(n = \sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_{i}}\right)
\end{align*}